# Python **obj.__dict__ equilavent command

Tags: python

I'm wondering if there is any more pythonic call in func_wrap to, without modifying func or the func_wrap header, call the function func?

```
class Foo(object):
  a = 1
  b = 2

class Bar(object):
  c = 3

def func_wrap(foo_obj, bar_obj):
  return func(a=foo_obj.a, b=foo_obj.b, c=bar_obj.c)

def func(a, b, c):
  return a + b + c
```

Something more along the lines of:

```
def func_wrap(foo_obj, bar_obj):
  return func(**foo_obj.__dict__ , **bar_obj.__dict__)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`vars` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars):

```
def func_wrap(foo_obj):
    return func(**vars(foo_obj))
```

which comes down to the same thing.

Comment: is it possible to pass in multiple vars if I have more parameters which come from multiple objects? (edited question accordingly)

Comment: @MattStokes: You can use `func(**dict(vars(ob1), **vars(ob2)))` to combine two objects, multiple objects require a loop where you update one dictionary with all options, *then* pass that dictionary on to the function.